# How to assign multiple value from HashMap to variables in Java?

Tags: java, stream, hashmap

I have a HashMap and assign key-value pairs to variable as shown below:

```java
Map<UUID, EmployeeDTO> result = employeeService.getEmployees(employeeUuids);

UUID key = result.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey();
EmployeeDTO value = result.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
```

However, I am not sure about what is a proper way to assign multiple values from this HashMap. I thought a loop of course, but for naming variables, maybe there would be a better approaches. Any idea?

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> {
    UUID key1 = k;
    EmployeeDTO value1 = v;

    //  what about the other values?
    UUID key2 = k;
    EmployeeDTO value2 = v;
});
```

Comment: You cannot dynamically create local variables like `key2` and `key3`. You need a data structure for that such as a `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create variables without knowing the size of the map, so you need to store the keys and the values in two separate data structures, for example `List`:

```
List<UUID> keys = new ArrayList<>();
List<EmployeeDTO> values = new ArrayList<>();
map.forEach((k, v) -> {
    keys.add(k);
    values.add(k);
});
```

In case the size of the map is known, you can store the entries in a list and assign the corresponding keys and values:

```
List<Map.Entry<UUID, EmployeeDTO>> entriesList = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());

UUID key1 = entriesList.get(0).getKey();
EmployeeDTO value1 = entriesList.get(0).getValue();

UUID key2 = entriesList.get(1).getKey();
EmployeeDTO value2 = entriesList.get(1).getValue();

// etc.
```

Obviously you need to do that for each key/value. It is theoretically possible to use a loop and some nasty reflection on the object that holds the variables, but this will do way more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically create local variables like `key2` and `key3`. You need a data structure for that such as a `List`. An example:

```
List<UUID> uuids = new ArrayList<>(result.size());
List<EmployeeDTO> employees = new ArrayList<>(result.size());
result.forEach((k,v)->{
    uuids.add(k);
    employees.add(v);
});
```

You can then access them using `uuids.get(0)`, `uuids.get(1)` and so on, same for `employees.get(i)`.

Comment: @fish_and_chips Thanks a lot amigo. I would vote up but unfortunately not enough reputation. Any vote up for my question pls?

Answer (score -1):

You should use a List in value like

```java
Map<UUID, List<EmployeeDTO>> result
```

And then

```java
result.get(KEY).add(VALUE);
```

You are now able to have multiple values for a single key

Comment: The question is not asking for multiple values per key.

Comment: @fish_and_chips Yes, but nevertheless it is useful and deserve vote up. So, I would vote up but unfortunately not enough reputation. Any vote up for my question pls?

Comment: @IQbrod Thanks a lot amigo. I would vote up but unfortunately not enough reputation. Any vote up for my question pls?